# jQuery slider plugin taking time to bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [Flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html) to display items and their respective images.

What happens is that on page load, all li's are displayed first like a list with bullets. After a second, the plugin gets applied.

I tried hiding the original list (without plugin applied) through `CSS` but didn't work.

**Edit**: I also tried document.ready. That didn't help either.

**Edit**: I am also OK with the solution that suggests to hide the content unless the plugin is applied.

Let me know if any other details are needed. Excuse me for English is not my first language.

Here is my code.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide4.jpg" />
    </li>
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide4.jpg" />
    </li>
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$(window).load(function() {

$('#carousel').flexslider({
   animation: "slide",
   controlNav: false,
   animationLoop: false,
   slideshow: false,
   itemWidth: 210,
   itemMargin: 5,
   asNavFor: '#slider'
});

$('#slider').flexslider({
   animation: "slide",
   controlNav: false,
   animationLoop: false,
   slideshow: false,
   sync: "#carousel"
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using document ready event instead of window load -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
```

Comment: Thanks. I also tried document.ready. That didn't help either.

Comment: Load your flexslider.js at the top of the file in your header section  if not.

Comment: Nope. Didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the fact that you are performing the plugin initialization at the `$(window).load(...)` event. The thing with `load` event is that it waits until *all* the content and *all* the images on the pages are fully fetched. You probably need here an `$(document).ready(...)` event handler. This will execute more early and you'll hopefully won't see any blinks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: 'slide',
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider',
  });

  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: 'slide',
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: '#carousel',
  });
});
```

You can read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) about the `$(document).ready(...)` event. It is useful in a lot of the contexts. You'll have a good amount of benefit from reading about the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), which is a modern alternative to the jQuery's `ready` and it is preferred these days.

Comment: Thanks. I also tried document.ready. That didn't help either.

Comment: Can we get a codepen with the problem? That was the most obvious thing to suggest without having one.